# Searching a Spilled Array for a Negative Number

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some type of VBA code to search a spilled array for any negative numbers and then delete a row from a table in another sheet. This spilled array can be seen in the image below, starting in E8. The worksheet it is found on is called "DASHBOARD"

spilled array

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Karja.png)

Provided below is an image of the table I'd like to delete a final row from if a negative value is found in the spilled array. The table is called "Table1" and is found on a worksheet called ledger.

table

[image]

I already have a macro put in place to delete a row if a condition is met. I have this located in a hidden sheet called "Data" .....please see below. I'm just not sure how I could modify this to search for a negative number in a spilled array and then delete the row in Table1. I'm not sure whether I should try to put this new code in a sheet or in ThisWorkbook or in a Module. I apologize if this is hard to follow. I'm new to VBA.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

   'if portfolio is less than 55% stocks
   If Sheets("Ledger").Range("AC2").Value < 0.55 Then

   'find new last row
   newLastRow = Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row()

   'delete new last row
   Intersect(Range("ABCDEF"), Rows(newLastRow)).Delete
   End If
   End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **spilled array** in column **B** and you need to determine if a negative value exists in the array:

```
=IF(MIN(B1#)<0,"negative exists","no negatives")
```

In VBA, you would apply similar logic.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would write the code in vba. I understand the logic. Writing the code has been the issue. If you can give me anymore help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've had difficult finding information online regarding how to write code pertaining to range that is a spilled array. Also, the code that I had written in my sheet module will only work if a condition is met in that sheet and it finds the bottom row of a range in that sheet. What I want to do is slightly more difficult because the condition must be met on one sheet, then the action (deleting the last row of the table) takes place in another worksheet.